# Need help for a problem: A Wordpress published page turns into draft by itself

Tags: wordpress

recently I found out that one of the most important pages on my site will turned into draft mode automatically.  It happens every 2 or 3 days, I can't tell.

I have asked an expert that I worked with to check it, he said he couldn't find any problem.
And strangely, it doesn't happen to other pages/posts but only to this specific important page!

Is it possible that because the page is too loaded with images and text?
Or maybe some plugins or even a malware that does it?
the page is [here](https://www.topicnews.cn/about).

Comment: Have you checked if the post_modified timestamp of the page matches approximately  the execution time of any of your WordPress cron jobs? N.B. this only is useful if there is timely activity on your web site as WordPress cron jobs only run as a side effect when an HTTP request is made. Do you have any cron jobs that run at an interval of 2 or 3 days?

Comment: Cron job - Maybe related to wp rocket?  Thank you for giving me the direction, I'll check it out.

Comment: Ok the problem REALLY is one of the cron jobs, found it and got rid of it, back to normal.  Thanks alot!!!!